# Why is "System Reserved" mounted in Windows 7 and how can I make it hidden again?

Tags: windows-7, mount

A fresh installation of Windows 7, however the System Reserved ~100MB is mounted at `G:`.

Why is this? How can I make it hidden again?

Answer (score 1):

You can make it hidden by going into Disk Management. Right click the System Reserve volume and click "change drive path." Click the drive path and click **remove**.